# Can anyone tell me where can I get sample UML diagrams for an ERP system?

Tags: uml, sample

I want to study an ERP system. For that I want to study its processes. So if anyone can give me some useful links then it will be helpful to me, thanks.

Comment: This question would be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

May you find something useful here

[Model-Driven ERP Implementation](http://campus.hesge.ch/dugerdilp/_private/ICEIS2006.pdf)

[UML Diagram](http://www.neogia.org/UML_Diagram)

Answer (score 2):

Check out The Data Model Resource Book series from Silverstron. Not UML... but close.
[Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237), [volume 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471353485).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ERP systems, most of them are designed for a specific industry, sometimes even for a specific corporation.

So you have to choose a specific ERP system first, and then analyze it. A good starting point would be the [list of ERP systems on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=erp).

Another starting point would be [this document](http://www.dsmforum.org/events/DSVL02/linvald.pdf) about the general use of UML diagrams in ERP systems.

Comment: but if you can give me some useful use case diagram sources then it will be useful for me

Answer (score 0):

This is a tipical UML, I was looking for same that you, to show this to a client, and this is the best example
https://creately.com/diagram/example/hn34ipx61/ERP

Comment: Please provide a bit more context for your link.